# What area deals with the extraction of words with similar characteristics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a dataset with annotations in the form: `<Word/Phrase, Ontology Class>`, where Ontology Class can be one of the following `{Physical Object, Action, Quantity}`. I have created this dataset manually for my particular ontology model from a large corpus of text.

Because this process was manual, I am sure that I may have missed some words/phrases from my corpus. If such is the case, I am looking at ways to automatically extract other words from the same corpus that have the "characteristics" as these words in the labeled dataset. Therefore, the first task is to define "characteristics" before I even go with the task of extracting other words.

Are there any standard techniques that I can use to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Sorry. I should have mentioned that these are domain-specific words not found in WordNet.

Comment: Look at [NLTK](nltk.org) and [pyWordNet](http://osteele.com/projects/pywordnet/)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Thank you. I edited my question: These are domain specific words not found in Wordnet so I am presuming that Wordnet might not be useful perhaps? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In the abstract sense, you'll need something that functions like wordnet. If these are real words, then a dictionary/thesaurus should do. So you might end up needing to do some legwork with [thesaurus.com](thesaurus.com)/[urban dictionary](urbandictionary.com) or something similar

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Hmm... Some are dictionary based words but a lot of them are bigrams or trigrams which are not easily found in a dictionary so I guess I should resort to some other techniques. Thank you for helping me out though.

Comment: That's a tough one.. perhaps try to harness google's API (don't know if they have one for this) and google for "define: <word>". Then compare that definition to several other tags. Though, an easier way (since this is an annoyance, and not the real problem you want to deal with) might be to print all untagged words and  a sorted (how to sort) list of tagged words. Then select the most similar word... just a thought

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Thank you for your time. I will try out your suggestions during my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [chapter 6](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html) of the NLTK book. From what you have described, it sounds like a supervised classification technique based on feature ("characteristic") extraction might be a good choice. From the book:

> A classifier is called supervised if it is built based on training
>   corpora containing the correct label for each input.

You can use some of the data that you have manually encoded to train your classifier. It might look like this:

```
def word_features(name):
    features = {}
    features["firstletter"] = name[0].lower()
    features["lastletter"] = name[-1].lower()
    for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        features["count(%s)" % letter] = name.lower().count(letter)
        features["has(%s)" % letter] = (letter in name.lower())
    return features
```

Next you can train your classifier on some of the data you have already tagged:

```
>> words = [('Rock', 'Physical Object'), ('Play', 'Action'), ... ]
>>> featuresets = [(word_features(n), g) for (n,g) in words]
>>> train_set, test_set = featuresets[500:], featuresets[:500]
>>> classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

You should probably train on half of the data you already tagged. That way you can test the accuracy of the classifier with the other half. Keep working on the features until the accuracy of the classifier is as you desire.

```
nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
```

You can check individual classifications as follows:

```
classifier.classify(word_features('Gold'))
```

If you are not familiar with NLTK, then you can read the previous chapters as well.

Comment: This is definitely a good starting point. Thank you for your time. I will try this now. Any suggestions on what other classifiers I can try out?

Comment: Huh?  This is the right idea, but getting a good classification based on the features of the letters is not going to work.  It's not realistic to assume there are any correlations between the letters and the features

Comment: Also, could you give me an example of how to incorporate preceding and succeeding parts of speech into the features?

Comment: Take a look at chapter 7 http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html.

Answer (score 1):

As jfocht has said, you need a classifier to do this.  To train a classifier, you need a set of training data of 'things' with features and their classification.  You can then feed in a new 'thing' with features and get out the classification.

The kicker here is that you don't have features, you just have the words.   One idea is to use WordNet, which is a fancy dictionary, to generate features from the definitions of the words.  One of WordNet's best features is it has a hierarchy for a word e.g.,

```
cat -> animal -> living thing -> thing ....
```

You **might** be able to do this simply by following the hierarchy, but if you can't, you could add features from it and train it.  This will likely work much better than using the words themselves as features.

Regardless of whether you find Wordnet to be useful, you need a feature set to train your classifier, and you also have to label all your unclassified data with those features, so unless you have some way to do the feature part computationally, it's going to be less work to do it by hand

Comment: +1 Thank you. I will think about how to represent my training data as features.

Comment: From what you say you have one feature in your training set, `OntologyClass`. Your "bigrams and trigrams" (i.e., phrases) should be treated as atomic by the classifier, so unless you already have a good recognizer for them, look into "chunking", and perhaps "named entity recognition" (check the NLTK book).